# how to integrate Paynimo payment gateway in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to integrate techprocess payment gateway in my ios application. kindly tell me the frameworks for this payment gateway.

Link : [Techprocess](http://techprocess.co.in)

Comment: i ask paynimo payment integration. not in app purchase

Comment: Like :https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/mobile/ios-integration-guide/?

Comment: its not paypal integration. its paynimo integration with iOS.

Comment: you didn't mentioned that in your question, you just said integrate techprocess payment gateway.

Comment: techprocess payment also know as paynimo only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You need to get UTA and Live Paynimo SDK from Techprocess.

- Application Name : MerchantSampleApp
- Project Name : MerchantSampleApp
- Import Header  : import
- Minimum iOS : 7.0
- xcode  : xcode 5.1 and xcode 6.1 and above

Create Blank Application as:

- View Controller : CheckoutViewCon troller
- Layout View :PayminoStyle

Set Windows Background Color to White.

2) Add PayminoStyle.h and .m file into project.

3) Framework Integration:

- Target->Build Phases->Link Binary with Libraries->click(+)->Add
  Other-> Paynimolib.framework
- When framework add on project
- Add Other Library
- MessageUI.framework
- MobileCoreServices.framework
- SystemConfiguration.framework
- CFNetwork.framework
- Security.framework
- Foundation.framework
- CoreGraphics.framework
- UIKit.framework
- AVFoundation.framework
- AudioToolbox.framework
- CoreMedia.framework
- MobileCoreServices.framework
- Target ->Build Settings -> Other Linker Flag set value “-ObjC” ,”-
  lstdc++”,”-lc++”
- Target -> info add "Fonts provided application” 
  1.Roboto-Bold-webfont.ttf 
  2.Roboto-Light-webfont.ttf 
  3.Roboto-Regular-webfont.ttf

4) Bundle integration: 
    •   Target->Build Phases->Copy Bundle Resources->click(+)->Add Other-> Paynimolib.bundle

- In info.plist file add below key (Updated iOS 10.0) to scan card  NSCameraUsageDescription

used to scan card

5) Implement functionality in CheckoutViewController

1. import header file “#import ”
2. Initialise Checkout object and set value in that object.

then add a button ,

```
- (IBAction)payBtnTap:(id)sender {

    Checkout *checkoutObj = [Checkout new];

    //Merchant
    [checkoutObj setMerchantIdentifier:@"MerchantIdentifier"];//you need to get from techprocess

    [checkoutObj setPaymentTransactionIdentifier:@"TXN001234"];

    [checkoutObj setPaymentTransactionReference:@"ORD0001"];

    [checkoutObj setPaymentTransactionType:@"SALE"];

    [checkoutObj setPaymentTransactionSubType:@"DEBIT"];

    [checkoutObj setPaymentTransactionCurrency:@"INR"];

    [checkoutObj setPaymentTransactionAmount:@"1.0"];

    [checkoutObj setPaymentTransactionDateTime:@"24-11-2016"];

    //Consumer
    [checkoutObj setConsumerIdentifier:@"appusername"];

    [checkoutObj setConsumerEmailID:@"appuser@gmail.com"];

    [checkoutObj setConsumerMobileNumber:@"mobilenumber"];

    [checkoutObj setConsumerAccountNumber:@""];

    [checkoutObj addCartItem:@"Top" amount:@"1.0" SurchargeOrDiscount:@"0.0" SKU:@"com.companyname.yourappname" Description:@"" ProviderID:@"yourcompanyidfrom techprocess" Reference:@"Test" CommisionAmt:@""];

  PMPaymentOptionView *payView = [[PMPaymentOptionView alloc] initWithPublicKey:@"MerchantIdentifier" checkout:checkoutObj paymentType:@"Netbanking" success:^(id resObject ) {

        NSLog(@"%@",resObject);

    } failure:^(NSDictionary *failDict) {

        NSLog(@"%@",failDict);

    } cancel:^{


    }];

    [self.navigationController presentViewController:payView animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

hope this will be helpfull. and also refer UTA and Live PaynimoSDK document.
And this is for netbanking process.

Comment: can someone help me to integrate paynimo sdk in swift?. is there link to a sample implementation